# Making a custom Arduino

Tags: microcontroller, programming, atmel, atmega328p, bootloader

I am working on making a custom Arduino board but I have some confusions regarding that. I have seen all the documentations but am confused regarding the ICSP pins and the communication through the USB-Serial. I have seen that the step to be take is to put the Arduino bootloader in the bootloader section of the At-mega328p and then the program can be added using the USB-serial. Is this fine??Secondly if this is correct then why dont we use the USB to put the bootloader as well instead of having the ICSP of the SPI pins. Kindly help me regarding that as I am working on these for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you program an ATMega328 though its serial port, what is actually happening is this:

- There's a program, the bootloader, which communicates through the serial port
- That program knows how to "self-program" the CPU: it reads the data from the serial port (in one of a number of formats) and decides to reprogram its own flash/EEPROM/etc.

If that program is absent or buggy, you won't be able to do this.

However, you can always program the CPU through its ICSP pins because that doesn't use a program on the CPU, it uses a state machine specially designed for this purpose.  The specifications for this protocol are that the CPU is held in reset state, and the external programmer clocks some data in a particualr format.

Some types of CPU come from the factory with bootloaders installed, but most do not.  If you're making enough of them, it can be convenient to order your parts with your own code already installed.

Answer (score 0):

The ATMega328 does not have a built-in USB bootloader, so the chip cannot initially be programmed through the USB-Serial.

Once the bootloader code is loaded, you can then use either method.

The ICSP pins also allow hardware debugging such as single step, which the Arduino platform does not support for the ATMega328 chip.

Answer (score 0):

An empty ATMega328P can't do anything if you have not loaded any code to it, and the only way to load any code to an empty ATMega328P is via ICSP pins, and only when you have programmed a serial bootoader via ICSP fist, then you can communicate and reprogram it via the serial UART interface, maybe using an USB to UART interface.

So you can't upload a bootoader via USB because you don't have a bootloader yet.